# How to modify the javascript code to receive input from the user?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am struck with my language translation tool . 
Here is the code that google translate API has .
I have to modify this code to receive input from the user in a text box and then identify the language it is typed in. Currently the code is picking up the values from id="sourceText" . 
I need to put in a text box there to make it a simple dynamic tool . Please tell me what modifications should be made to add a text box and receive its input and detect the language ?  Thanks...

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Translate API Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
  <div id="sourceText">Hello world</div>
<div id="translation"></div>
<script>
  function translateText(response) { 
    document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  }
</script>
<script>
  var newScript = document.createElement('script');
  newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
  var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
  newScript.src = source;

  // When we add this script to the head, the request is sent off.
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`<div id="sourceText">Hello world</div>`

to

`<textarea id="sourceText">Hello World</textarea>`

Also update this line:

`var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").value);`

---

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Translate API Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
  <textarea id="sourceText">Hello world</textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Translate" onclick="submit()" />
<div id="translation"></div>
<script>
  function translateText(response) { 
    document.getElementById("translation").innerHTML += "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  }

 function submit() {
  var newScript = document.createElement('script');
  newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
  var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
  newScript.src = source;

  // When we add this script to the head, the request is sent off.
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
 }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Got this point..Thnks. Now how shold I code a button to submit my text area value and invoke appropriate function .. Please guide .. Thanks

Comment: Wrap the javascript in a function called `submit()` and add `<input type="button" onclick="submit()" />`

Comment: Please help me with wrapping up the js functions ..Tried but failed(i am still a beginner) Cant we use the translateText(response) function in onclick ? Thanks alot for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing

```
  <div id='mySource'>
```

into

```
  <textarea id='mySource'>
```

and put the code responsible for translation into function, and add a button "trasnalte", which onclick event would launch translating function?